# Find the best lag from the numpy.correlate output

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I am using the following code to do auto-correlation on data_1 and data_2:

```
result = numpy.correlate(data_1, data_2, mode='full')
```

The result is also the time series. I also normalized result to result1:

```
result1 = StandardScaler().fit_transform(result.astype('float32').reshape(-1, 1))
```

Then here is the plot, `data_1` is black, `data_2` is red, `result1` is green:

[image]

I know there is a lag between `data_1` and `data_2`, so I am wondering what's the best way to find the lag? Thanks!

Comment: This is not **auto**correlation. Autocorrelation is between a signal and a delayed copy of the same signal. You have two signals, data1 and data2.

Answer (score 13):

`numpy.correlate` does not center the data, so one should do it prior to calling the method:

```
corr = np.correlate(data_1 - np.mean(data_1), 
                    data_2 - np.mean(data_2),
                    mode='full')
```

This only changes `corr` by a constant, but still, a reasonable thing to do: uncorrelated shifts will show up as 0.

Second, your chart with all three things on one horizontal scale doesn't seem helpful; with `mode='full'` the length of correlation array is about twice the length of original ones.

Picking the maximum of `corr` with `corr.argmax()` is a reasonable thing to do. One just has to be aware of how the index works here. With mode='full' the 0th index of `corr` corresponds to the shift `k` in the [formula `sum_n a[n+k] * conj(v[n])`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) being `1 - len(a)`, meaning `a` is moved extremely far to the left so that there is just one element of overlap between shifted `a` and `v`. So, subtracting `len(a) - 1` from this index gives the actual shift of `a` with respect to `v`.

A made-up example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data_1 = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, 100))
data_1 += np.random.uniform(size=data_1.shape)   # noise
data_2 = np.cos(np.linspace(0, 7, 70))
data_2 += np.random.uniform(size=data_2.shape)   # noise
corr = np.correlate(data_1 - np.mean(data_1), 
                    data_2 - np.mean(data_2),
                    mode='full')
plt.plot(corr)
plt.show()
lag = corr.argmax() - (len(data_1) - 1)
print(lag)
plt.plot(data_1, 'r*')
plt.plot(data_2, 'b*')
plt.show()
```

Here the lag is printed as -14 or -15 (depending on random noise) which on this scale means -1.4 or -1.5. This is reasonable, as sin is trailing cos by pi/2, or about 1.57. In other words, moving the red dots to the left by 14-15 elements maximizes the match with the blue dots.

Data:

[image: data]

Correlation:

[image: correlation]

Comment: I'm using this function, but I'm not used to the return of a non correlation function.  I'm creating a list of correlations to append and I'm finding that the lag specified is not higher than the correlation at lag 0.  But the corr outputed for index 0 isn't the argmax... which is why I wish this function outputted correlations... now I'm going to have to do it by hand

Comment: I don't think you need to remove the means, correlate should do this by definition.