# Delay in Savitzky-Golay filtering

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I am applying a Savitzky-Golay filter to a signal, using the scipy function.

I need to calculate the lag of the filtered signal, and how much is it behind the original signal.

Could someone shed some light on this matter? How could I calculate it with scipy? How should I interpret the result correctly?

I would be very grateful!

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far?
Also, seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372282/find-the-best-lag-from-the-numpy-correlate-output

Comment: When you ask about ‘lag’ do you mean latency - i.e. the number of samples that have to be provided before an output is produced? The latency of a digital filter is the window size.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`savgol_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) is designed to have zero lag.  This is implemented by explicitly handling the edges using polynomial interpolation when `mode` is `"interp"` (the default), or by padding when `mode` is not `"interp"`.

Here's an example in which a unit pulse, `x`, is filtered.  Note that the filtered signal `y` is aligned with the pulse--there is no lag.

```
In [110]: x = np.zeros(51)

In [111]: x[25] = 1

In [112]: y = savgol_filter(x, 25, 7)

In [113]: plot(x, label='x')
Out[113]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1276b1ba8>]

In [114]: plot(y, '.-', markersize=5, label='y')
Out[114]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1276cc358>]

In [115]: grid()

In [116]: legend()
Out[116]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x1276db9e8>
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Assuming by lag you mean latency, I think what you are describing is a simulation of ‘no lag’ - the filter has to have a window full of samples to produce a ‘correct’ output

Comment: Yes, I'm looking that my problem should refer to latency, because Savitzky-Golay doesn'tt change the position of the peaks. Thanks for the help, I'm very new in this topic.

Comment: Anyway this answer is both wrong (because a real filter would of course have lag, not being a prescient thing that can see even one sample into a linear time future, let alone a whole window-full) - and right (because the scipy function can pretend to not have lag as long as you present it future samples). Hmm.

Comment: @barny, what is your definition of a "real" filter?  Many signal processing libraries (scipy, matlab, etc) have filtering functions that act on a given *array* of data.  That is, the complete signal is available.  So the notion of "future samples" and causality are not relevant.  If you understand that, you'll see that there is nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: *"... are not relevant"* -- well, not until the filter tries to look beyond the given signal, either forward or backward in time.  That's where `savgol_filter` and other filtering functions have to make some assumptions about what's beyond the given data.

Comment: And that’s why this answer is right. But a real-world real-time filter cannot do that - it needs a window full of data, and the OP was asking about latency, i.e. that window - which means the scipy filter can only *simulate* no lag because it has a full window. C’est la vie: right *and* wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about lag/latency of a digital filter: the only possible answer for a real-time filter is that the latency is determined entirely by the window size of the filter.

Non-realtime filters (e.g, where the full set of samples is provided to the filter, as for e.g. the scipy Savitsky-Golay filter) can pretend/simulate filtering at the ‘time’ of the current sample, but only by looking ahead at the full window.

Some might protest that this is demonstrably how e.g. the scipy Savitzky-Goay filter works, and that’s entirely correct, but nevertheless if you are asking about latency of a filter, which can only mean the delay that a real-time real-world filter will apply to real-time samples, the only possible answer is: this is only and undeniably/incontrovertibly determined by the window size.